# Setting ProductCode for python script (Citrix environment)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, error-000824, basic-license-level, citrix

I have set up a python script in ArcToolbox for our users.

However when running it with ArcView 10.0 licensing the script fails with:

> ERROR 000824:  The tool is not licensed

I think it's an Identity_analysis command triggering this error.

I've googled the topic and it seems there was a SetProduct(code) command, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Can someone provide the syntax to get this running, or is it a limitation running ArcGIS in a Citrix environment?

Comment: What tools are you using?  Do they require an extension, such as Spatial License?

Comment: The only commands in this python script are from the _management and _analysis toolboxes.

Comment: It seems like there are problems with license borrowing with [ArcGIS 10 over Citrix](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/6343-ArcGIS-with-Citrix-Performance-and-Known-Issues).  I don't know if it is related, but the problem appears to persist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is **not** a Citrix issue.

You get:

> ERROR 000824: The tool is not licensed

because you are running the ArcView (Basic) license level of ArcGIS (for) Desktop.

As you say, it is being triggered by the Identity (Analysis) tool, which at 10.0 (and 10.1/10.2) requires an ArcEditor (Standard) or ArcInfo (Advanced) license.  You can verify this license requirement at the bottom of its **[10.0 help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000n000000)**.

As a workaround, instead of using Identity in your script try **[Union](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Union/00080000000s000000/)**.  This works at all three license levels, but creates a geographically larger output that you can quickly  "filter" back to match that from Identity by using the **[Select](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Select/000800000005000000/)** tool.

Comment: I'll take that as an answer, even though I think there is the capability to specify the level of licensing you want to use programatically. Changing the Identity commands to Unions probably would work, unless there are other Advanced tools being used with no alternatives.   Thanks everyone for your suggestions.

Comment: If you were also asking "How to specify ArcGIS license level to use within ArcPy over Citrix?", then it may be worth posting that as a new Question.

Answer (score 2):

The identify_analysis tool requires Advanced or ArcInfo. Excluding any Citrix issues, you should be able to add an import for ArcInfo above your import for ArcPy, like:

```
import arcinfo
import arcpy
```

The [ESRI documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Accessing_licenses_and_extensions_in_Python/002z0000000z000000/) for that.

Comment: I tried that and with an Arcview level license the script fails immediately with the following error: <type 'exceptions.RuntimeError'>: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.   Still runs fine with an ArcInfo license.